# How to re-use a module several times in the same `main.tf`?

Tags: terraform

I created a module for a re-usable piece of infrastructure. The module is a **project**, so each time we want to create a new project and the related infrastructure items, we could use this module:

```
module "project1" {
source = ".modules/project_module"
    project_id = "project1"
    ...
}

module "project2" {
source = ".modules/project_module"
    project_id = "project2"
    ...
}
```

The module uses the google provider to create resources on GCP.

Unfortunately, this didn't work as hoped. First, each new project requires to invoke `terraform init` and second, it is impossible to remove a project, because when removing a module from the `main.tf` file, Terraform complains that without the Google provider it cannot destroy resources. For example:

```
module.project1.google_storage_bucket_iam_member.some-bucket: 
configuration for module.project1.provider.google is not present; a provider configuration block is required for all operations
```

Is there a way to use several times the same module in the same `main.tf`?  I realize that ideally I should write a provider, but I would like to avoid that for now.

Comment: Is this unique to the GCP provider? This works completely fine with the AWS provider.

Comment: I suspect this is due to the content of the module and that it's setting up the provider config in that module. Could you edit your question to include a [mcve] of what the module has in it that exhibits this behaviour please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was something inconsistent in the state. Burning the end, after re-creating the project from scratch while keeping the Google provider outside of the module, it worked.